# Recursively check the difference between files in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to recursively check the difference between files in 2 separate directories in shell. NOTE :- both directories are identical only the root name is different

[image]

In the diagram shown above I want to "diff ROOT_A/A.md5 ROOT_B/A.md5" recursively in my script file for all files in the root directory.

```
for filename in ROOT_A/*.md5; do
    diff ($filename | cut -d '/' -f 2) (ROOT_B/$filename) >> logfile.txt done
```

However, This doesn't work. can someone help me out with this. Thanks

Comment: Where's the command you've tried? It's not like we can help you with no code to see where the issue is...

Comment: Updated my question with my code snippet. Thanks

Comment: In Bash, instead of `cut` you would better use the built-in functionality to modify the value of a variable by removing a matching prefix -- `"${filename##*/}"` will remove everything up to and including the last `/`. And you of course wanted to say `diff $(...)` (note the `$`); and `(ROOT_B/$filename)` does not mean what you seem to be believe it means.

Comment: BTW, putting `>logfile.txt` *after* the `done` is much more efficient than putting a `>>logfile.txt` inside the loop (since it opens the output file just once, instead of reopening it once every time it wants to write a single command's output), and will also have the (presumably desirable) side effect of clearing the file *just once* when the loop starts (so you aren't mixing multiple runs' output).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your shell is Bash:

```sh
ROOT_A='...'
ROOT_B='...'
for file in "$ROOT_A"/*.md5; do
  ! test -r "$file" || ! test -r "$ROOT_B/${file##*/}" && continue
  echo "Comparing $file with $ROOT_B/${file##*/}"
  diff "$file" "$ROOT_B/${file##*/}"
done
```

As @CharlesDuffy observes, if the files are truly MD5 sums (or other such kind of checksums), `diff` should be replaced with `cmp` because it doesn't matter *how* different the files are, only if they are the same or different.

Comment: I'd suggest `cmp` rather than `diff` -- being a smaller tool that can exit immediately as soon as it's answered the question "are these files different?", without needing to answer "how are they different?". (Especially true with `cmp -q`, where only inspecting exit status -- granted, this shouldn't be the case with md5 checksums, but `cmp -q` can determine that files differ *without even opening them* just by looking at the `stat` data if their sizes are different, or that they're identical if they're backed by the same inode).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: The OP wants to diff the files.

Comment: You're right -- OP is asking for something that's pretty clearly the wrong thing in the context of md5sums, but still, it *is* what they're asking for.

Comment: Hey @CharlesDuffy, I am new to scripting and yes I am trying to compare the two directories using diff and creating a new logfile.txt for the same. Is there a better way to do this?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SagarNair, ...depends on what the actual output you want is. If it's a list of only identical files, or only different files, there are certainly approaches more efficient than using `diff`. If you want to see the actual lines that differ (arranged into the smallest possible set of line-oriented deltas), then `diff` is the right tool -- it's just that the extra work it does has a cost in performance and memory usage.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy So in my ROOT_A and ROOT_B ideally all the md5 files should be identical. So what I was doing is recursively iterating through each file and using diff to find any differences and appending it to a logfile to check if there is an inconsistency.

Comment: @SagarNair, ...but you only care about finding a list of files that aren't identical? Then it'll be faster to have `cmp -q "$file" "$ROOT_B/${file##*/}" || printf '%s\n' "${file##*/}"` inside your loop to just generate a list of files that differ, without needing to compute a patch to transform between them.

Comment: (granted, if these are one-line files, the performance delta is fairly small -- it's when comparing larger files that `diff` gets expensive).